# Fetch value from Map<Object, Object> for a particular key in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `Map<Object, Object>` in Java, and I want to fetch value for a particular key.

`sampleMap = { id = customerName , year = 2020, month = March }`

I want to do something like

`String name = sampleMap.get("month").toString();`

But this is not working for me. How do I fetch values for a particular key in this case.

Note: I don't want to run a loop and check for each key as the Map is quite big in this case.

Comment: Why is it `Map<Object, Object>` and not `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: Anyway, define "not working" - because it is working just fine for me. Perhaps you should show us the real code, how you initialize that `Map` and how you put values in it.

Comment: I am not defining this Map in the code but getting it from somewhere else as the input parameter.

Comment: `sampleMap.get("month")` returns value assigned to the key "month" just fine. Based on what you've provided, without reproducible code snippet, we can't really help you.

Comment: @Pooja _`I am not defining this Map in the code but getting it from somewhere else as the input parameter.`_ What is the **data type** of the **input parameter** ?

Comment: @Bishan Map<Object, Object>

Comment: @Pooja Ok. What is the error you got with this code? `String name = sampleMap.get("month").toString();`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

According to the data given in the question and comments, below code will fix your issue.

```
String name = sampleMap.containsKey("month") ? ( 
 (sampleMap.get("month") != null) ? sampleMap.get("month").toString() : "N/A") 
: "N/A";
```

You will get `java.lang.NullPointerException` when the key is not available or the value is **null**. So you should perform key check and null check before acquire data using the key.